# VS Code Haskero debug configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, debug, haskell

I am trying to configure VS Code for Haskell. I use Haskero extension, which works great for code navigation, highlighting etc. However, for some reason when I try to start a debugging session I cannot create proper configuration as VS Code does not create launch.json file.

When I click "Add configuration" I see a pop-up window saying "Select environment" and I see only Node.js in the list. When I click "More..." and select Haskero from the bigger list, it shows an extension configuration instead of creating debug one.

[Debug panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xHQw.png)

[Pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnfyE.png)

[Extensions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Nd1.png)

Could you please help me to figure out how to configure debug for Haskero?

Comment: Please try to add some screenshots to the description of your scenario. Imaginary debugging of _Microsoft_ _Visual Studio_ Environments tends to be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. Screenshots added.